# What is the difference between SESSION_DRIVER=file and SESSION_DRIVER=redis in env laravel?

Tags: laravel, redis, environment-variables, laravel-5.3, driver

I use laravel 5.3

In my localhost, the env like this :

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

In my production, the env like this :

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Almost all the same, just SESSION_DRIVER different

What is the difference between SESSION_DRIVER=file and SESSION_DRIVER=redis?

Comment: ... https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#configuration ...

Comment: @lagbox, Okay thanks. I will try to read it. I just need a spesific answer

Comment: your answer is right there... it says what all the drivers are in a nice list :)

Comment: @lagbox, Okay. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session driver file stores session data in a file, redis driver stores session data in redis, redis driver is obviously faster. For example

```
Session::set('user', $user); //this is stored in file or redis
Session::get('user'); //this is get from file or redis
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you explain also the usefulness of `CACHE_DRIVER=redis `and `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis`?

Comment: It is the same, in first case cache is saved to file in second to redis. e.g. for Cache::put('user', $user);

Comment: Redis is not obviously faster than file system.. I think you might be thinking strictly in terms of interprocess communication, single server "Pets" - however most modern implementations utilize shared redis, in which case, you go over the network, and local filesystem might be faster in some cases.

Comment: shared redis is faster that shared file system, local redis is also faster than local file system

Answer (score 2):

`SESSION_DRIVER` define how Laravel will store sessions data, if you don't know/have redis, you should set this to "file".

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you explain also the usefulness of `CACHE_DRIVER=redis `and `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis`?

Comment: @SuccessMan CACHE_DRIVER is about the same but for Laravel's cached data. QUEUE_DRIVER should be for automatic task performed by Laravel (not 100% sure on this one).